# how to store all data with flutter sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, flutter

i am using sqflite package to store and get data from storage but i realized that all data are not stored altough i used the `insert` sqlfite function as below :

```
static Future insertData(String table, data) async {
    Database db = await DatabaseHelper.database;
    var result = await db.insert('$table', data,
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
    print("resultat $result");
    return result;
  }
```

and just in case i did not do it well, the database initialization and creation :

```
    class DatabaseHelper {
  static DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper;
  static Database _database;

  DatabaseHelper._createInstance();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._createInstance();
  factory DatabaseHelper() {
    if (_databaseHelper == null) {
      _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper._createInstance();
    }
    return _databaseHelper;
  }

  static Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await initializeDatabase();
    }
    return _database;
  }

  static Future<Database> initializeDatabase() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
    String path = directory.path + 'mpata.db';

    var mpataDatabase =
        await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);
    return mpataDatabase;
  }

  static void _createDb(Database db, int newVersion) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE operationType(operationTypeId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, libelle TEXT);');

    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE accounType(accountTypeId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, libelle TEXT);');

    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE country(countryIsoCode INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);');

    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE user(userId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, email TEXT, firstName TEXT, lastName TEXT, msisdnUsr TEXT);');
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE otheruser(userId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, email TEXT, firstName TEXT, lastName TEXT, msisdnUsr TEXT);');

    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE accounts(accountId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,active INTEGER,country TEXT,createDate TEXT,currency TEXT,expire TEXT,msisdn TEXT,numero TEXT,pin TEXT,solde DOUBLE,updateDate TEXT);');
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE other(accountId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,active INTEGER,country TEXT,createDate TEXT,currency TEXT,expire TEXT,msisdn TEXT,numero TEXT,pin TEXT,solde DOUBLE,updateDate TEXT);');
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE transactions(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,account INTEGER,other INTEGER,amount INTEGER,fees INTEGER,operationDate TEXT,operationTypeId INTEGER,reference TEXT,status TEXT,frais INTEGER,description TEXT,admin TEXT,libelleOperation TEXT,accountId INTEGER,userId INTEGER,firstName TEXT,lastName TEXT,email TEXT,msisdnUsr TEXT);');

    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE productCategory(productCategoryId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,libelle TEXT, description TEXT);');

    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE notification(notificationId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,notificationType TEXT, message TEXT, statut TEXT, createDate TEXT);');
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE notifications(notificationId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,notificationType TEXT, message TEXT, statut TEXT, createDate TEXT);');
  }
}
```

and finally the way i store each item i received from online mode:

```
var dataUserAccount = {
          'userId': item['account']['user']['userId'],
          'email': item['account']['user']['email'],
          'firstName': item['account']['user']['firstName'],
          'lastName': item['account']['user']['lastName'],
          'msisdnUsr': item['account']['user']['msisdn']
        };
var idusr = await DatabaseHelper.insertData('user', dataUserAccount);
```

i am using sqflite to apply offline on my application, and when i realize some tests, the results in online mode are greater than the one with offline mode. and i print the raws number of the sqlite tables and the length of the results got from a web service. there are not the same. so i don't know why the `insert`  function is not working for all cases.

Comment: Are you saving items that already been saved previously? Or all items unique?

Comment: according to the conflictAlgorithm option, when items are the same, the new item replace the old @fartem

Comment: Are you sure that all data correct?